# java application deployment on tomcat server on red hat?

Tags: java, tomcat5.5

I have a java web service application, i created a .WAR file. 
and now i have loaded .WAR file in a folder that is in a root
for example

/mytestdir/mywebapp.WAR

now i want my tomcat5 to run this file that is out of tomcat5 webapps directry.
Please help me how can i run this .WAR that i should be able to access like this

http://www.mysite.com:8080/mywebapp

in .WAR file i have a code that needs to access some root level folders.

this is my first deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a Tomcat *Context*.

In order to do so, open `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml` and add a `Context` that will point to the war file location. For example:

```
<Context path="/MyApplication" docBase="/mytestdir/mywebapp.WAR" reloadable="false" />
```

Then, restart your Tomcat instance and you're done.

Comment: This is a possible solution, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `config.xml` 
Smth, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context path="/mywebapp"  docBase="/mytestdir/mywebapp.WAR">
```

[see docBase attribute](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html)